# Solr DataImportHandler MySQL 5.0 SELECT CONCAT query results are base64 encoded

Tags: mysql, solr, dataimporthandler

I have Solr 4.0 up and running and using DataImportHandler to import data from MySQL.

I have notcied that if I point DataImportHandler at MySQL 5.5 data source everyhting works as expected. However when using exactly the same Solr/DataImportHandler config and exactly the same database but running on MySQL 5.0 certain fields come back base64 encoded.

Relevant entries in data-config.xml

```
       <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
                    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
                    name="DB-SOURCE"
                    url="jdbc:mysql://dbhost/dbname"
                    user="user"    
                    password="password"
    />

   <document name="articles">
<entity name="article_ph" transformer="HTMLStripTransformer" dataSource="DB-SOURCE" pk="article_id" 
                            query="SELECT 'Politics Home' AS article_site, 
                                            CONCAT('ph-article-', article_id) AS article_id,
                                            article_title,
                                            article_text_plain AS article_content,
                                            article_articletype_id,
                                            article_datetime AS article_date,
                                            'Uncategorised' AS article_section,
                                            'Non Member' AS article_source
                                            FROM articles 
                                            WHERE 
                                            article_datetime!='0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
                                            AND article_datetime is NOT NULL 
                                            AND article_live=1 
                                            AND article_text_plain!='' 
                                            AND article_text_plain IS NOT NULL 
                                            AND article_title is NOT NULL
                                            AND article_title !=''">
            <field column="ARTICLE_SITE" name="article_site" />
            <field column="ARTICLE_ID" name="article_id" />
            <field column="ARTICLE_TITLE" name="article_title" />
            <field column="ARTICLE_CONTENT" name="article_content" stripHTML="true" />
            <field column="ARTICLE_DATE" name="article_date" />
            <field column="ARTICLE_SECTION" name="article_section" />
            <field column="ARTICLE_SOURCE" name="article_source" />
            <entity name="articletype_name" dataSource="DB-SOURCE" 
                            query="SELECT 
                            articletype_name 
                            FROM articletypes 
                            WHERE articletype_id='${article_ph.article_articletype_id}'">
    <field column="articletype_name" name="article_type"/>
            </entity>
</entity>
```

When I run import pointing at MySQL 5.5 I get :

```
<arr name="article_id"><str>ph-article-124</str></arr>
```

When I run import pointing at MySQL 5.0 I get articles with base64 encode IDs :

```
<arr name="article_id"><str>cGgtYXJ0aWNsZS0xMjQ=</str></arr>
```

All other fields come back correctly.

Collation and character sets on both DBs are the same.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting it back to string

```
CONCAT('ph-article-', CAST(article_id AS CHAR(50))
```

Comment: Looks promising. I have not tested that yet but according to MySQL reference manual on CONCAT function : " ... If all arguments are nonbinary strings, the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent string form. This is a nonbinary string as of MySQL 5.5.3. Before 5.5.3, it is a binary string; to to avoid that and produce a nonbinary string, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:... "

Comment: This worked for me on Mysql 5.1.73. I was concatenating two text fields and two numeric fields and was having the exact same problem. Reading this I thought I might be able to get away with making sure that the _final_ value was cast to not be numeric, but I had to cast both of the numeric fields. `concat_ws( "|", h2.heading, r2.ref_desc, CAST(h2.count1 AS CHAR(7)),cast(h2.count2 AS CHAR(7))) as encodedSolrField`. Thanks for this!